# Simulate private bitcoin network with random peer discovery

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain, bitcoind, bitcoin-testnet

I am looking for a way to simulate a 1000 node bitcoin network on my private LAN/Wifi network.

I read the developer's guide: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#regtest-mode which mentions the `regtest` mode that works primarily for single nodes or specified nodes and not random nodes like the actual network.

Some people might suggest using the `testnet` mode but that is not useful for me as I want to check a new protocol for bitcoins that wont be supported by the unknown nodes over the `testnet` network.

To put it simply, I am looking to simulate a complete bitcoin network within my LAN/Wifi network.

Comment: You can model the whatever network you wish to using the regtest mode right..What other aspect of the network are you looking out for?

Comment: @everconfusedGuy What I want is exact simulation of `testnet` or `main` net on a private network. That means, I want to start a new blockchain for nodes on my LAN, they should connect only within themselves via the peer discovery method that is exactly like the actual bitcoin network. First time a node joins this custom network, it should connect to custom hardcoded nodes(as I have disabled DNS discovery in my code) by sending `version` and `verack` messages and then exchange `getaddr` and `addr` messages to discover other nodes on the network.

Comment: Despite the fact that this question should probably be moved to the bitcoin site, it's an interesting one. Did you ever figure this out? According to https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Satoshi_Client_Node_Discovery#Command_Line_Provided_Addresses , the addresses provided via command line (addnode) are not advertised in response to a getaddr request. It seems chicken vs egg: if they are not advertised, then how will the network grow? Or is it simply not part of the regtest mode?

Comment: did you figure a way out to form this network? I am using docker containers in regtest mode, but need to find a way to automatically detect and connect to some peers.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to sandbox them if you are trying to connect on a LAN.

- specify a unique port (if listening) and rpcport (if using rpc) for
  each node
- specify a unique data directory for each node

Use mkdir to create directories the first time

```
mkdir $HOME/regtest/A/
mkdir $HOME/regtest/B/
mkdir $HOME/regtest/C/
```

Modify & run this bash script(note the port numbers, there are 9 of them in this example) to connect to each other in round-robin.

```
#!/bin/bash
bitcoind -server -listen -port=17590 -rpcuser=<user> -rpcpassword=<pass> -rpcport=16590 -datadir=$HOME/regtest/A/ -addnode=localhost:17591 -regtest -pid=$HOME/regtest/A/ -daemon -debug
bitcoind -server -listen -port=17591 -rpcuser=<user> -rpcpassword=<pass> -rpcport=16591 -datadir=$HOME/regtest/B/ -addnode=localhost:17592 -regtest -pid=$HOME/regtest/B/ -daemon -debug
bitcoind -server -listen -port=17592 -rpcuser=<user> -rpcpassword=<pass> -rpcport=16592 -datadir=$HOME/regtest/C/ -addnode=localhost:17590 -regtest -pid=$HOME/regtest/A/ -daemon -debug
```

Since you want to research peer discovery you might want to look at the difference between trying `-connect` instead of `-addnode`